# Removing MouseListener() from a JLabel

Tags: java, swing, jlabel, mouselistener

I added a `MouseListener` to a `JLabel`. Now if I want to disable this `MouseListener` associated with the `JLabel`, when the label is clicked once, how can I do it.

I know there is a big way to set a boolean or int variable when the label is clicked and then call a method and remove `MouseListener` there, but I want to learn a compact and easy way. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your mouse listener:

```
public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent event) {
    // Do stuff...
    ((Component) event.getSource()).removeMouseListener(this);
}
```

Comment: That's about as simple as it will get.

Answer (score 2):

What's wrong with `label.removeMouseListener(listener)`? It works just fine. If you want to create listener that removes itself call `label.removeMouseListener(this)`